# MySQL table engine not being updated (Or update not being reflected)

Tags: mysql, database, magento, alter-table

I have a large MySQL database with over 400 tables. Almost all of the tables need to be changed to InnoDB per framework requirements.

I'm running the following query to see the current table engines for the db:

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASE_NAME';
```

I've created a flat file with a list of all the tables w/the proper "ALTER TABLE" syntax:

```
 ALTER TABLE  wishlist_item ENGINE=InnoDB;
 ...etc...
```

I've run this file w/the following syntax:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE_NAME < alter_staging_tables.txt
```

However, when I run:

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASE_NAME';
```

It still shows ALL the tables as MyISAM, despite my file running and changing the engine types. I've even gone in, ran a single alter by hand:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE  zendesk ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 8 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

But when I do the select:

```
| zendesk                                           | MyISAM |
```

It shows the table as still MyISAM. What am I doing wrong?
TIA.

Update: MySQL Version:

```
mysql -v
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 306675
Server version: 5.0.77-log Source distribution
```

Update:
So the change is NOT sticking:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE  zendesk ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 8 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1266 | Using storage engine MyISAM for table 'zendesk' | 
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Version of MySQL? Some of them lie about these things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure InnoDB is enabled? You can check with [SHOW ENGINES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-engines.html).

Note that by default, MySQL will simply ignore unrecognized `ENGINE` directives, and issue a warning (unless you've set [NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution)). Your `ALTER TABLE` command did issue one warning, which may have been due to this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE  zendesk ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 8 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You're correct, the engine type is disabled. Trying to figure out now best way to enable it.